# Passing in the chosen color variable from UIButton to another view

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am coding in the latest xcode in Objective-C and I have been pretty much stuck last two days.
I am making an application that will allow the users to select what color clothing they are wearing. So for example, if I am wearing a black and white shirt, I can choose clothing = shirt and colours = black and white.

Here is a screen shot of how my app looks like: (everything you see here are UIButtons so you can click them and for colours, I have it set up so the colours you have chosen will highlight)

![my app]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBFud.png "myApp"

so in the first image, you would choose your clothing and once you hit the button, the second view will come up and in here, you would choose the colours.
So far so good. But I run into some problems when I want to use the colours chosen to bring back to the first view. If I picked black and white for the colours of my shirt, I want my app to bring back that data and change the "shirt" button's background colour to change to black and white to indicate to the users those are the colours you have chosen. '

Here are my codes so far.

changeClothes.h (first view): http://pastebin.com/xPMNAnCY

changeClothes.m: http://pastebin.com/MdjMPK6r

chooseColors.h (second view): http://pastebin.com/Zb4aXvzV

chooseColors.m: http://pastebin.com/RHTxfwW5

Any help would be appreciated.

Many, many, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could work with the delegation pattern!
Define a protocol for your chooseColors class and make the changeClothes class implement this protocol. changeClothes class then works as a delegate of chooseColors class. In chooseColors class, when a color is selected via button, call the delegate with this event! Back in changeClothes class you can dismiss the modal chooseColors controller and perform some actions in changeClothes controller according to the selected color.

More on the delegation pattern: [Cocoa Core Competencies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)
(On the bottom you have a reference to a example project from apple)

Also please take a look at the coding guidelines for cocoa!
You named your classes wrongly, see: [Coding Guidelines for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146i)

Comment: Hi I am looking at coding guidelines for cocoa and is wondering what I named wrong. Could you give me an example. Also, I will read over the cocoa core competencies right now and see if that will help me.

Comment: Class names should start with an upper case letter! Also `changeClothes` indicates an action -> this would be appropriate for a method name, not a class name. Better would be `ClothingChangeViewController`.

Comment: thanks! fixed it to have uppercase letters. also, i've been reading the cocoa core competencies but im not really understanding it and still having trouble figuring out a solution. are there any good tutorials i can have a look at?

Comment: Did you get to this apple guide, explaining the delegation mechanisam in more detail: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18

Comment: reading it now. i am getting a lot of errors by just changing the names of the classes so I think im going to leave them as they are for now but start naming them by the correct format from now on. I gave the link quick glance and its kind of hard to understand so I probably have to read it over and over. and I am still trying to find a good tutorial online since seeing an example would help me a lot in this case. thanks for the help though

Comment: Well, almost every example by apple has somehow delegation in it! Take a closer look at the following example project: iPhoneCoreDataRecipes
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I got the general idea of how delegation works now but I still don't know how to do what I want yet. I will try to make a custom delegation class as it shows there and see if I can do it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have enough rep to comment, so resorting to answer. If it's helpful you should really give Nenad the green check mark)

Building on @Nenad's answer: have a look at the "[Communicating With Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18)" section of the Apple documentation. It explains delegation in greater detail.